# How to move functions into a namespace?

Tags: c++

The project calls functions from a library. I want to move those functions behind a namespace so that is easier to spot the places on the codebase where those functions are being called.

How functions are being called:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

How I want to call them:

```
#include "myfoo.h"

int main()
{
    thatlibrary::my_foo();
    thatlibrary::my_bar();

    return 0;
}
```

How I implemented that:

myfoo.h

```
namespace thatlibrary
{
    void my_foo();
    void my_bar();
}
```

myfoo.cpp

```
namespace thatlibrary
{
    void my_foo()
    {
        foo();
    }

    void my_bar()
    {
        bar();
    }
}
```

Wondering if there is any other solution? Perhaps more elegant.

Comment: So this library doesn't wrap all its names in a namespace? :/

Comment: Is the library header-only? That would be an easier case than a library that has a binary component.

Comment: @Enlico the library has no namespace.

Comment: @JaMiT Why? Anyway, is not header-only (it's .h + .dll)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How not to pollute the global namespace with declarations of a C header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263405/how-not-to-pollute-the-global-namespace-with-declarations-of-a-c-header)

Comment: @KcFnMi Because definitions in a header can be moved to a namespace (rather easily), while definitions in a .dll cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `using` declaration in your namespace:

```cpp
// global namespace
int foo() {
    return 1;
}

namespace thatlibrary {
    using ::foo;
}

auto i = thatlibrary::foo();
```

Notice that the name `foo` is still available in the global namespace, though.

```cpp
// in global namespace
auto j = foo(); // works just fine
// from anywhere
auto k = ::foo(); // works just fine
```

---

I think the library is poorly designed, if it declares all its stuff in the global namespace.

Comment: I would prefer to hide the original names i.e. `foo()`. Are there alternatives?

Comment: [Not a "clean" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33263405/5825294).